# Can't access the json values in my ajax success in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

now guys i know this is a simple error but no matter what i try i cant access the json values whenever i use alert after parse json it shows me undefined 
why is it caused ?
here is my code 
script

```
function getfriend_requests()
{
var id=$('.id_data').attr('value');

jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("user/getallfriends"); ?>',
                data:{id:id},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data)
                {   

                     var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                     var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
                     alert(json);
                     $.each(json,function(key,data)
                  {
                      alert(data.object);
                  });
            }
            });
}
```

now the controller

```
public function getallfriends()
{
  $id=$this->input->post('id');
  $this->load->model('Pmodel');
  $data['senders']=$this->Pmodel->get_all_user_friends_sender($id);


  $data['recievers']=$this->Pmodel->get_all_user_friends_reciever($id);

  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

now the model

```
public function get_all_user_friends_sender($id)
{


     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('user_friend');
     $this->db->join('user_data', 'user_friend.senders_id = user_data.id');
     $this->db->join('user', 'user_friend.senders_id = user.id');
     $this->db->where('user_friend.senders_id',$id);

    $query = $this->db->get();



        $row = $query->result_array();
     // print_r($row);
        return($row);



}
public function get_all_user_friends_reciever($id)
{

     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('user_friend');
     $this->db->join('user_data', 'user_friend.recievers_id = user_data.id');
     $this->db->join('user', 'user_friend.recievers_id = user.id');
     $this->db->where('user_friend.recievers_id',$id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

        $row = $query->result_array();
     // print_r($row);
        return($row);



}
```

now when i try to return the value with result_array iy shows me undefined value but if i use $row_array it return only single value from each model.
can you tell me where i am going wrong?
[image: response][image]

Comment: Why do you stringify the response just to parse it back to json again in the next row? You've set `json` as dataType for your ajax call, so it should already be a json object. You should also post the json response you return from your PHP.

Comment: do a `console.log(data)` in the response part of your ajax call to see what your browser has to say

Comment: You have `array` of json because of `$query->result_array()` so see on console what is output on `console.log(data);`.

Comment: see the edited image it shows the reponse

Comment: the response is bringing all the values that i want to show @Hekmat

Comment: The `Object` in your console is not a key, it's telling you what data type it is. You're getting an object with two properties, which each contains an array with multiple elements.

Comment: yes i am getting an object that contains the values get my $result_array @MagnusEriksson

Comment: ya you have array of objects.try to get values using `data.key`.because data pointing to your object.

Comment: see the edited answer@Hekmat

Answer (score 1):

You have `array of objects` in json response so in success function try like this..

```
             $.each(json,function(key,data)
                  {
                      alert(data.key);//where key is key of pointing object
                  });
```

Comment: what values are inside object in console.

Comment: is it possible to convert the json object into an array @Hekmat

Comment: what value on alert(data.id)?

Comment: undefined @Hekmat

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try to change

`echo json_encode($data);`

to

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: In json response you don't have array so you can't do $.each of json. You have to do $.each from json.senders and $.each from json.receivers and remove   `var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data); var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);` your response it's a json

Comment: how would i do it seprately for both senders and recievers can you please guide me @Gerard

Comment: You can add php responses to unique array `$data[]['senders']` and `$data[]['receivers'] or simply iterate separately: ` $.each(json.senders,function(key,data)` $.each(json.receivers,function(key,data)`